# How can one IIS6 .NET app appear as subsite of another?

Tags: .net-2.0, iis-6

SiteA.com and siteB.com are .NET 2.0 apps on IIS6.  SiteA uses SSL.

Can I set things up so siteA.com/train gets people to siteB.com?

Are there multiple ways to do this?  How would a good way be configured?

Comment: The question is a little confusing. Perhaps if you could explain why you are trying to do that it would help someone give a more appropriate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to MyComputer, right+mouse+click and chose Manage.  Go to IIS/Websites and open up your sitename.com website.. navigate to the directory sitename.com/train.  right+mouse+click on the train folder and chose "properties". Under the "directory" property click "create".  I think that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Yes, thanks.  Tradeoffs:  sites A & B no longer have separate logs & can't be restarted separately.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a subdirectory of a site point to the root, and you can't have two site instances with the same domain name- the DNS record for www.sitename.com points to exactly one IP address.  I think you'd be better off with something like http://train.sitename.com.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can have two site instances with the same domain, one could work with www.domain.com and the other to only work on domain.com. DNS can distinguish between the two.